# Javascript event listener not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

My map never loads when I include a device ready listener (The image capture never works, but that is a different issue....). Without the device ready listener, the map works just fine.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

P.S. I'm zipping the files, putting it on phonegap and running it on my moto x.

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
  <div data-role="page" data-control-title="Home" id="page1">
  <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>
          Campus Kitchen
      </h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
      <div id="map">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad(){
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady(){
          var map = L.map('map');

          L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map)

          map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

          function onLocationFound(e) {
            var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

            L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("Your pickup spot is in this area").openPopup();
            L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
          }

          map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

          function onLocationError(e) {
            alert(e.message);
          }

          map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

          function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData){
            var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
            smallImage.style.display = "block";
            smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
          }

          function capturePhoto(){
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL});
          }

        }

        </script>


     </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="camerainput">
        <button onclick="capturePhoto();" data-role="button">Capture Picture of Food</button>
        <img style="display:none; width:60px; height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
      </div>
```